# Spark reference table

Tags: apache-spark

A Spark RDD contains a collection, each element represents a request.

A Scala function will be passed to the RDD, and, for each RDD element, the function will create a modified request.

For each collection element\request, a lookup table needs to be referenced.
The maximum size of the reference table will be 200 rows.

How performance and scalability, how should the lookup table (which is used within the function) be modeled?

1. Spark Broadcast variable.
2. Separate Spark RDD.
3. Scala immutable collection.

Perhaps there is a another option I have not considered.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the size of your RDDs, but giving that your reference table will have about 200 rows, I think the best option would be to use a broadcast variable.

If you used a separate RDD, you could make spark to repartition the request RDDs and making an innecesary shuffle.

Comment: What about if the data was held as a collection within a Scala function. When the function got passed to the RDD (using map or foreach), would that not also distribute the data to each partition and work in the same way as a broadcast variable?

Comment: The you will be serializing all the method, plus some more metadata, which could have worst performance.

Comment: BTW. there is another option you did not mention, which is using mapPartition and getting a new DB driver instance for each partition, then you could query the table from there. Sometimes you can find this approach useful

Comment: Thanks very much. Does mapPartition presume that the table is stored in a DB - I just want a Scala collection. If not, what would be the advantages of using mapPartition over a broadcast variable?

Comment: mapPartition does some action over the list of elements in every partition. It allows you to get instances of non-serializable objects and use them inside the partition.  the assumption of the database was just mine

Comment: To clarify, I am working on the understanding that a broadcast variable can contain a collection like a list or map, or an array.